# sonarqube missing project dashboard

Tags: sonarqube, project, dashboard, sonarqube-web

I have SonarQube 6.1. When I click on a project entry from the main dashboards projects widget, I get to a project home page where it says "quality gate passed" and where some issues are listed ('Bugs', 'Vulnerabilities', 'Code smells' and 'Duplications').

On the left side, close to the top, below the project name, there is a "home" icon and to the right it says 'Issuses', 'Measures', 'Code' and 'Administration'.

When I tried to get to a project dashboard - similar to the main dashboard, but specific to the project - I found this page http://docs.sonarqube.org/display/SONARQUBE56/Project+Dashboards. It shows in part a project home page that looks very different from my installations projects home pages. Instead of 'Issuses', 'Measures', 'Code' and 'Administration', like in my case, it has 'Technical Debt', 'Coverage' and so on and also 'Dashboards'. I guess thats where I should go looking for a project dashboard. But that menu item is just missing (along with others) from what my SonarQube shows me!

What can I do?

Comment: As clearly stated at the top of the linked page, you're looking at an _archived_ version of the docs for an old version. Here is the documentation for the current version: http://docs.sonarqube.org/display/SONAR/Documentation (currently 6.1)

Comment: Thanks for the info. So, project dashboards are gone? Why? They seem beneficial to me. Is there a surrogate?

Comment: There does not really seem to be a replacement: http://stackoverflow.com/a/40265544/106567

Answer (score 5):

Here's some background info on the why:

- https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/sonarqube/Ir1sE6OVW40/64rLvZJFDAAJ
- https://blog.sonarsource.com/sonarqube-6-x-series-focused-and-efficient/

Hence my recommendation is basically to stay with your current 5.x version, or upgrade to 6.0 but not beyond, and then wait until mid 2017 and see what new cross project governance features are coming then.

Answer (score 3):

The project dashboards are dropped in SonarQube 6.1. And the global dashboard are probably dropped in the next SonarQube version. https://jira.sonarsource.com/browse/SONAR-7915

If you want to use the project dashboards you could use the SonarQube versions 5.6.x or 6.0

Comment: Thanks! Dashboards seem like the main GUI feature of SonarQube to me. Why would they drop them?

Comment: Is there any alternative for the custom dashboards ?