# SonarQube 6.1: How can I see the changes over time without the dashboards?

Tags: sonarqube, sonarqube-web

SonarQube used to have dashboards which were quite convenient to display how metrics changed over time. There was even a dashboard called "Time Machine".

How can I see this sort of information in SonarQube 6.1? I appreciate the new focus on the "leak period" but this is not everything I care about.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Go to the project's Measures space and drill in on the metric of interest. You should find a history graph there.

**UPDATE** These history graphs moved into [the Activity page in 6.3](https://docs.sonarsource.com/sonarqube/latest/user-guide/activity-and-history/)

Comment: Ok. That allows me to see the history for one metric which does not seem to be too useful. It also seems impossible to choose the period that is displayed... are there any plans to bring back something like the dashboards where I can see the history of several metrics at once?

Comment: Not currently, no.

Comment: Thanks for your feedback. Is this something you are going to discuss or should I put this as a feature request on the mailing list?

Comment: No plans to discuss @StefanEgli. The discussion was about removing.

Comment: That is not a replacement for time machine. How can I see correlations between metrics over time? How can I see all quality improvements of a newer version on one page? Developers used to motivate themselves by seeing how they have increased metrics.

Comment: Is there manual how can i use period2 (sonar.timemachine.period1), period3, period4, period5 in the version 6.1 and above? I've researched a lot of different sources, but without result.