# Is there a place to see the timeline widget with custom leak period?

Tags: sonarqube, sonarqube-web

Before 6.1, we were able to do so in a custom project dashboard. Actually, I can only see history measure by measure, but not on a dashboard.

Am I missing something?

Comment: Unfortunately dashboards were removed: http://stackoverflow.com/q/40186532/106567
http://stackoverflow.com/q/40263360/106567